# Why does my heavily divided surface look like it has flat shading?

Tags: modeling, normals, geometry-nodes, subdivision-surface

Even though my surface has smooth shading on and is heavily subdivided, the geometry seems to be faceted. Anyone know why?!

[Project File Linked Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PTnfdOMK39wge3YT4MVAxv2Qob0nku7v/view?usp=sharing)

[image: As you can see here, there are "edges" to the rounds.]

[image: The object is so subdivided it looks black..]

[image: Here is the geometry node setup I used to create the ripples. Link to tutorial I used here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dvMyBVRit0]

Comment: subdivide your other object too, the one you use as a source of data for displacement... try to compress file when saving or set in preferences

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you refer to those segments visible in your first picture then you need to subdivide the other mesh, the ring, the one you use to deform the grid... if you ask about the faces in the third image it is more a smoothing problem, may need an extra subdivision and use a 'set shade smooth' node... but I see you got it covered in the third picture

guess you are using a 2.93 version of blender, that smoothing node may not be there..? I'm new to GN so never used those attribute nodes either

[image]

Comment: Fuck yeah! That worked. Appreciate you!! @alambre

Comment: no problem, looks like a cool project